# One session per tab with Selenium Web-driver?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser

I would like to create a new session for each tab I open and then control the sessions individually using Selenium python. Is this possible?

Comment: A tab is the same session of your driver - but yes you can  have multiple tabs and you can manage them individually but not run them concurrently - you will need to switch tabs to control them. it will goto tab a, do action. Go to tab b do action etc..

Comment: they will share session data - just like it does in a normal browser when you open two tabs. So independent (isolated) no, but individually controllable if you switch between them

Comment: Multiple browsers or api. Depends what you want to do

Comment: Firefox has an official addon that does this, but I'm not sure if you can get selenium to interact with the addon. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/  If you figure out a way to do it, I would love to know how.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on why selenium is a requirement for this? Sometimes people use selenium when requests or similar would work just fine (and give you the isolated sessions).

Comment: @reynoldsnlp Does my answer help?

Comment: @Lindau why do you want exactly tabs? Did you try just to start two chrome browsers independently?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. What do you mean by "session"? If you mean the server, the server uses cookies so different tabs are the same session. And in the client, you can create a new test for each session. But what do you mean by "create a new session for each tab"?

Answer (score 2):

> @reynoldsnp: Firefox has an official addon that does this, but I'm not sure if you can get selenium to interact with the addon. addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers If you figure out a way to do it, I would love to know how.

(I can't comment yet due to my reputation score, therefore quoted comment).

I don't know how to actually interact with the extension but if you have a known set of sites you would like to open:

Try this:

1. Make a firefox profile for your use with selenium. [Multiple profiles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Multiple_profiles)

   > Windows 8/8.1/10:
   > Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> on your keyboard.
   > Type `firefox --new-instance --ProfileManager`
2. Open Firefox in that profile by selecting the new profile in the setup wizard. Install the extension in that profile.

[image: selecting profile top open firefox with]

3. Set up the containers you would like in the extension, to, by default, open up with a specific site.

[image: BY default open up sites with a container]
[image: default opening sites]
Ensure that the checkbox is ticked.

4. Start selenium with that profile like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('path/to/your/profile') # on windows found here: %APPDATA%/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

5. Navigate between tabs, effectively containers, using selenuium.

Comment: @Lindau do you mean this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/container-proxy/

Comment: Nice hack! I need to be able to dynamically open new isolated container tabs using selenium, so manually creating static containers for a profile isn't quite good enough for my needs.

Comment: @reynoldslp: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/6-easy-steps-testing-your-chrome-extension-selenium

Answer (score 0):

First, no, you cannot. While tabs runs as a process, they are attached to the session ID which initially open the browser. This is how the protocol works https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#new-session

They have, however, a unique ID which you can use to identify them by and switch between them.

```
driver.window_handles
```

will give you the list of open tabs. **Each tab is fully isolated**. You can now choose between

```
driver.switch_to_window("any open tab taken from windows handles list")
driver.do_something

driver.switch_to_window("any other tab from windows handles list")
driver.do_something_else_on_other_tab

# or (this option can let you run in parallel)
driver a = ChromeDriver()
driver b = ChromeDriver()

a.do_something
b.do_something
```

As suggested (and I personally do myself) open new session for each tab you want, that way you can parallel them and run much faster, all in all.

I am not sure the performance difference is that significant between multiple browsers or multiple tabs... they should use almost the same resources.